# how can I load a joomla module as a link?

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-module, loadmodule

this is my problem...

I have some of images and links that I want to load different joomla modules when user click on them.

mean each hyperlink can load another module|position

thanks all

Answer (score 1):

In case that you just want to call a module's content from a url the following answer will help you.

If you just want to show / hide a module in the same page you could use something similar to my previous answer: [Joomla 3 Show different modules on same position depending on toggler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31514913/3834042)

Joomla provides the functionality to call a specific file of the active template by adding the `tmpl=FILENAME` key/value to the url's query string.
All built-in templates have a component.php file if user wants to load the template with the component only. You could check the following link for more details: [Adding print pop-up functionality to a component](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_print_pop-up_functionality_to_a_component).

You could do something similar to only show the modules that you want to load.
You could copy the component.php to a new file (I have used custom.php) and added the following php code in the `<body> ... </body>` part.

```
<?php
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $selectedPosition = $jinput->getString("position", "");
    $selectedModule = $jinput->getString("module", "");
    $selectedModuleTitle = $jinput->getString("title");

    if($selectedPosition !== "") {
        $modules = JModuleHelper::getModules($selectedPosition);
        foreach ($modules as $module) {
            echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
        }
    } elseif ($selectedModule !== "") {
        $module = JModuleHelper::getModule($selectedModule, $selectedModuleTitle);
        echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
    }
?>
```

So with a similar way as [loadposition / loadmodule](https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F) works you could call the new template file using:

```
index.php?tmpl=custom&position=MODULE_POSITION
```

or

```
index.php?tmpl=custom&module=MODULE_TYPE
```

or

```
index.php?tmpl=custom&module=MODULE_TYPE&title=MODULE_TITLE
```

Optionally if you want to load the module with a specific style, you could pass it to the second paramter of the renderModule method like:

```
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module, array("style" => "xhtml"));
```

Hope this helps